# Padding of table inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have something like the following:

```css
.vili_horizontal_scroll_auto{
    width: auto;
    border: solid 1px #bed5cd;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.vili_table_padding{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

table.vili_wide_table {
  width: 1000px;
}

table {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="vili_horizontal_scroll_auto vili_table_padding">
  <table class="vili_wide_table">
    <tr><td>this should have whitespace on left and right</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="vili_horizontal_scroll_auto vili_table_padding">
  <table>
    <tr><td>this should have whitespace on left and right</td></tr>
    <tr><td>something very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that the table is correctly moved into the white space on the left hands side, however it still touches the screen on the right hand side even after scrolling to the far right.

How do I fix it so that the table is separated from the screen ends.

NOTE: The table is very wide so it is almost always wider than the screen.

Thank you

Comment: box-sizing:border-box?

Comment: Mind if I edit your post with an example?  Your problem seems clear to me but an example might help.

Comment: I tried to put this on both the div and the table but it did not change anything

Comment: @JonSG - no problem man :)

Comment: @mp3por If you make a example it will be better for understand the Q.

Comment: I edited the post to use the in-page sandbox and added a little text to clarify what I think your issue is.  Now, if it only gets passed the editing review....  If not, I **think** you can see what I proposed and make similar edits yourself.

Comment: @JonSG yeah man - nice work. My problem exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Change your width, it is overflowing the viewport. '100%' below works, but i am not sure it will cater to your needs, but your issue is basically the `width:1000px;`

```css
.vili_horizontal_scroll_auto{
    width: auto;
    border: solid 1px #bed5cd;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.vili_table_padding{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div class="vili_horizontal_scroll_auto vili_table_padding">
  <table>
    <tr><td>this should have whitespace on left and right</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Voting down and running away shows incompetence. What is wrong with my suggestion?

Comment: While I did not downvote you, your answer does not solve the issue.  The table in question is wider than the page (hence the scrollbars).  Setting the width of the table to 100% while allowing nice whitespace, is not an answer that solves the actual problem.